# Get-IISAppPool Property "Status" is always empty

Tags: powershell, iis, webserver, application-pool

When I type in `Get-IISAppPool` the `Status` property is always empty.

```
Get-IISAppPool | Select-Object Status
```

The application pools are running, and the names are correct.

Does anyone know why?

I'm not the creator of the application pools, could that be the reason?

Comment: In general, all IIS related scripts require administrator permissions (IIS Manager runs under administrator accounts only).

Comment: EDIT: Even though I'm logged in as admin, I had to start Powershell with rightclick -> Run as administrator in order to see the Status...

Comment: That's what Microsoft called UAC (starting from Windows Vista), something everyone should know for decades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know the status of the particular application pool using the powershell command.

Open PowerShell as administrator.

[image]

Run below command:

```
Get-WebAppPoolState -Name sample1
```

[image]

Note:
Check the name of the application pool you used in command that is available or not.

Regards,
Jalpa

Answer (score 7):

`Status` is not a property of the returned objects.  This is a calculated property for the default table output.  If you run this command:

`Get-IISAppPool  | Get-Member`

You will see there is no `Status` property.  There is, however, a `State` property, which, I guess, is where the default view gets it's value:

`State Property Microsoft.Web.Administration.ObjectState State {get;}`

In fact, if you look at the member information, apart from `Name`, none of the items in the default view appear as properties - well, they do, but under different names.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer! I just tried the following: Get-IISAppPool apppool_name | Select-Object state But it is still empty... any idea why?

Comment: Does `Status` have a value in the default table view?  What is shown if you do this:  `Get-IISAppPool ecowebABMSZ | Format-List *`?  Do you see anything in the IIS UI?

Comment: It's just empty. In the GUI from the IIS-Manager the state is "Running"

Comment: May be a permissions issue, but it's slightly odd that yours says 'Running' as that's not one of the allowed values: [ObjectState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.objectstate?view=iis-dotnet)

Comment: Sorry. It says "Started" I had to translate it from german to english.

Comment: No worries.  You'll probably need an IIS expert to advise why it isn't showing up, as it works as expected on my test server (which is a fairly simple setup).